# How to get Actual Make and Model of RAM

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a program that gathers information on a users Hardware ID so that it can only be attached to one PC, however, i am unable to figure out how to get the Manufacturer and Model of my RAM. I have tried to use Win32_PhysicalMemory class with WMI, and it doesn't give what i need. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671751/wmi-hardware-get-ram-info?rq=1

Comment: I looked at that, but saw that it did not have my answer in it, and i didn't want to necro a question that was made a long time ago.

Comment: That's fine; I linked it in case you hadn't seen it. However, you should definitely add the code that you've tried, otherwise your question will probably be closed.